# Getting whitescreen in Cordova application if I implementing React lazy loading with Suspense

Tags: reactjs, cordova, lazy-loading, react-suspense

Getting whitescreen in `Cordova` application if I implementing `React` `lazy` loading with `Suspense` if I remove lazy loading it is working fine.

Comment: Same here, @BHAR4T did you find any solution?